# How to make pop-up appears on site visit after certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, cookies, popup, timestamp

How do I make a pop-up that appears after the 3min of visitor stay on the site, it could be any page of the site.

I have read an article to use the setTimeout(function(){},time);
I am new to JS But every time I add the Timeout it breaks my below code.

Thanks for the help in advance!!

My code is below

```
            <div id="popup_a" class="popup_ABA">
      <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><div>THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="46%" align="right"><a href="#" class="nothanks">No</a></td>
                <td width="8%" class="popUpFooter_ABA">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="46%" align="left"><span class="popUpFooter_ABA"><a href="#" class="dosurvey" onClick="dosurvey('#', 'invitationwindow', 800, 550);">Yes</a></span></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {

    $.cookie('cisit292014', '1', {expires: 15, path: '/'});

    setInterval(function() {

    if ($.cookie('cisit292014') == 11){
        if ($.cookie('01092014') != '1') { // Check for cookie
    $.cookie('01092014', '1', { expires: 30, path: '/' });             
    // TO Unload the Popupbox
    function unloadPopupBox(){$('#popup_a').fadeOut("slow");}   
    // To Load the Popupbox
    function loadPopupBox(){$('#popup_a').fadeIn("slow");}

    // When site loaded, load the Popupbox First
    loadPopupBox();
    $('.nothanks').click( function() {unloadPopupBox();});
    $('.dosurvey').click( function() {unloadPopupBox();});

    }
    }       

    $.cookie('cisit292014', $.cookie('cisit292014') + '1' , {expires: 15, path: '/'});
    //alert($.cookie('cisit292014'));
    }, 20000);
    });

    function dosurvey(pageURL, title, w, h) {
    var left = (screen.width - w) / 2;
    var top = (screen.height - h) / 6;  

    var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=yes, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: looks like your only problem is you need to close the setInterval block. That's what's breaking your code currently

Comment: The above code works fine I get the popup for any visitor on page (not site), but when I try to make the popup load after 3min of visitor stay for site it breaks.

Comment: the code you have posted is not valid. So either you have not posted everything, or you are mistaken

Comment: Hi ControlAltDel, I have added the rest of the HTML code as well & all  are working fine.

Comment: any suggestion please